# Double calculation for rotate coordinate

Tags: javascript, 2d, calculation

I use this function and this works perfect if i use single rotation.

```js
export function rotate2dPlot(cx, cy, x, y, angle) {
  var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * -angle,
    cos = Math.cos(radians),
    sin = Math.sin(radians),
    nx = cos * (x - cx) + sin * (y - cy) + cx,
    ny = cos * (y - cy) - sin * (x - cx) + cy;
  return [nx, ny];
}
```

In my case i have rotation also for z axion. I dont see problem here.

I check my raycast, if work for first rotation then must work for double operation.

`triangle` is rezults object and this is my logic :

```js
// Look on this just like initial values 
      const triangleInZero = [
      [object.geometry.vertices[0 + a * 3], object.geometry.vertices[1 + a * 3], object.geometry.vertices[2 + a * 3]],
      [object.geometry.vertices[0 + b * 3], object.geometry.vertices[1 + b * 3], object.geometry.vertices[2 + b * 3]],
      [object.geometry.vertices[0 + c * 3], object.geometry.vertices[1 + c * 3], object.geometry.vertices[2 + c * 3]]
    ];

    var rez0, rez1, rez2;

    if (object.rotation.rx != 0) {
      rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][1], triangleInZero[0][2], object.rotation.rx);
      rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][1], triangleInZero[1][2], object.rotation.rx);
      rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][1], triangleInZero[2][2], object.rotation.rx);
      triangle = [
        [triangleInZero[0][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez0[1]],
        [triangleInZero[1][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez1[1]],
        [triangleInZero[2][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez2[1]]
      ];
    }
    // y z changed - rez0[1] is z
    if (object.rotation.ry != 0) {
      if (object.rotation.rx != 0) {

        // Y i Z
        // get already rotated y 
        const detY0 = rez0[0];
        const detY1 = rez1[0];
        const detY2 = rez2[0];

        rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][0], rez0[1], object.rotation.ry);
        rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][0], rez1[1], object.rotation.ry);
        rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][0], rez2[1], object.rotation.ry);

        // ????
        triangle = [
          [rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], detY0 + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez0[1]],
          [rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], detY1 + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez1[1]],
          [rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], detY2 + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez2[1]]
        ];

      } else {
        rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][0], triangleInZero[0][2], -object.rotation.ry);
        rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][0], triangleInZero[1][2], -object.rotation.ry);
        rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][0], triangleInZero[2][2], -object.rotation.ry);

        triangle = [
          [rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[0][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez0[1]],
          [rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[1][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez1[1]],
          [rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[2][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez2[1]]
        ];

      }
      
    }
```

Live demo : [DEMO](https://maximumroulette.com/apps/matrix-engine/app-build.html)

Source code most important files related to the this bug:

Draw function :
[draw func](https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/matrix-engine/blob/master/lib/matrix-draws.js)

Raycast function:
[raycast func](https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/matrix-engine/blob/master/lib/raycast.js)

I send every triangle by accessed by indices and i check it in raycast.
But my draw function have different calculation in moment of changing les 2 parameters like rotx and roty or any combination between rotx, roty, rotx.

Comment: So what is the question?  And what data is being passed through the algorithm that comes out incorrect, and what should be the expected result?

Comment: Thnk for response i updated question with demo ans source links.

Comment: for object.rotation.ry & object.rotation.rx != 0 raycast worked. I rotate all with bonus angle -90 .... i cant fix other combination ....